# Hide state in function call

Tags: erlang

I thinking about hide state from function call.
Example:

```
body_to_client(Req, ClientRef) ->
  case cowboy_req:body(Req) of
    {ok, Data, Req2} ->
      ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
      Req2;
    {more, Data, Req2} ->
      ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
      body_to_client(Req2, ClientRef)
  end.
```

But I want to divide this code on couple parts and hide implementation:

```
body_to_client(ReadRequestBody, ClientRef) ->
  case ReadRequestBody() of
    {ok, Data} ->
      ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
      ReadRequestBody;
    {more, Data} ->
      ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
      body_to_client(ReadRequestBody, ClientRef)
  end.
```

Where ReadRequestBody is a function which contains all details and state.
I think it should be something like this:

```
ReadRequestBody = fun() ->
    {Status, Data, Req2} = cowboy_req:body(Req),
    {Status, Data}
  end
```

But I don't know how to deal with Req2 and pass it in next call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to extract Req2 would be to return it with the rest of the result from `ReadRequestBody`:

```
ReadRequestBody = fun() ->
    {Status, Data, Req2} = cowboy_req:body(Req),
    {{Status, Data}, Req2}
  end
```

Which you then have to check, just like you were doing before anyway, but now with more syntax, a closure that you don't need and a few more lines to split the result and match its contents, etc. HAIR ON FIRE! AH! Let's bring the volume down a notch...

I feel like this whole thing is just getting over complicated, so maybe going the other direction, removing clever devices instead of adding them, reveals something. Let's see what it looks like without a `case`:

```
body_to_client({ok, Data, Req}, ClientRef) ->
    ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
    Req;
body_to_client({more, Data, Req}, ClientRef) ->
    ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
    body_to_client(cowboy_req:body(Req), ClientRef).
```

Now `body_to_client/2` is a named case of its own. But we're doing the same thing both times (always sending the Data to the ClientRef), which feels silly to write twice. There is really only a decision point regarding whether to to iterate or not. Let's distill that out:

```
body_to_client({Status, Data, Req}, ClientRef) ->
    ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
    check_status({Status, Req} ClientRef).

check_status({ok, Req}, _) ->
    Req;
check_status({more, Req}, ClientRef) ->
    body_to_client(cowboy_req:body(Req), ClientRef).
```

Now everything is named and the code is explicit about what each piece is doing. We could bring `check_status/2` back inside `body_to_client/2` as a `case` if it seems more readable:

```
body_to_client({Status, Data, Req}, ClientRef) ->
    ok = hackney:send_body(ClientRef, Data),
    case Status of
        ok   -> Req;
        more -> body_to_client(cowboy_req:body(Req), ClientRef)
    end.
```

Note that bringing a match that works fine as a named function into another function as a `case` is somewhat controversial. The name `body_to_client` is now a little lie, because this function does more than just send the body to the client (but the nature of this lie may or may not matter, depending on the rest of the code).

Comment: Thank you for the such deep answer